# How do I fix an AssertionError for a program executing various test cases?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, assertion

Here is my main function:
import unittest

```
def main():
# initial roster
    brave_roster = {
        "Austin Riley": "AB: 615, R: 90, H: 168, HR: 38, AVG: 0.273",
        "Ronald Acuna": "AB: 467, R: 71, H: 124, HR: 15, AVG: 0.266",
  }
    
    
    print("\t ***  Braves Stats!  ***\n")
    print("Welcome to My Braves Stats! What can I do for you?\n")
    print("  1. Search for a player")
    print("  2. Add a new player")
    print("  3. Remove a player")
    
    
    name = brave_roster
    stats = brave_roster
    choice = input("Please type your choice number:")
    if (choice == "1"):
        name = input("Enter the name of the player you want to lookup:\n")
        new_roster = lookup_player(brave_roster, name)
       
    elif (choice == "2"):
       name = input("Enter the name of the player you want to add:\n") 
       stats = input("Please add the player's stats:\n")
       new_play = add_player_to_dict(brave_roster,name,stats)
       
    else: 
        (choice == "3")
        name = input("Enter the name of the player you want to remove:\n")
        delete_in_dict(brave_roster,name)


#my code:

def lookup_player(brave_roster,name):
  
  if name in brave_roster:
    print("Here are", [name], "'s stats:", brave_roster[name])
    return brave_roster[name]
  else:
    print("The player doesn't exist in the roster")
    return "N/A"
    
def add_player_to_dict(brave_roster,name,stats):
  if name not in brave_roster:
    brave_roster[name] = stats
    print("Here's the complete team roster:\n")
    for name, stats in brave_roster.items():
      print(name, ':', stats)
  elif isinstance(brave_roster[name], list):
    brave_roster[name].append(stats)
    for name, stats in brave_roster.items():
      print(name, ':', stats)
  
  else:
    brave_roster[name] = [brave_roster[name], stats]
    print("That player does not exist in our roster")
  return  brave_roster
      
def delete_in_dict(brave_roster, name):
  
  if name in brave_roster:
    del brave_roster[name]
    return brave_roster
  else:
    print("\n uh typo?", [name], "does not play for us")
    return brave_roster

main()
        









# Testing code
class TestDictFunctions(unittest.TestCase):

  def test_search_player_success(self):
    test_dict = {
        "Austin Riley": "AB: 615, R: 90, H: 168, HR: 38, AVG: 0.273"
    }
    actual = test_dict["Austin Riley"]
    expected = lookup_player(test_dict, "Austin Riley")
    self.assertEqual(actual, expected)

  def test_search_player_no_result(self):
    test_dict = {
        "Austin Riley": "AB: 615, R: 90, H: 168, HR: 38, AVG: 0.273"
    }
    actual = "N/A"
    expected = lookup_player(test_dict, "Ronald Acuna")
    self.assertEqual(actual, expected)

  def test_add_player_sucess(self):
    test_dict = {
        "Austin Riley": "AB: 615, R: 90, H: 168, HR: 38, AVG: 0.273"
    }
    actual = {
        "Austin Riley": "AB: 615, R: 90, H: 168, HR: 38, AVG: 0.273",
        "Ronald Acuna": "AB: 467, R: 71, H: 124, HR: 15, AVG: 0.266"
    }
    expected = add_player_to_dict(test_dict, "Ronald Acuna", "AB: 467, R: 71, H: 124, HR: 15, AVG: 0.266")

    self.assertEqual(actual, expected)
```

This test case gives me an AssertionError when it encounters my add_player_to_dict function.

```
def test_add_player_duplicate(self):
        test_dict = {"Austin Riley": "AB: 615, R: 90, H: 168, HR: 38, AVG: 0.273"}
        actual = {"Austin Riley": "AB: 615, R: 90, H: 168, HR: 38, AVG: 0.273", "Austin Riley(2)": "AB: 350, R: 20, H: 120, HR: 5, AVG: 0.214"}
        expected = add_player_to_dict(test_dict, "Austin Riley", "AB: 350, R: 20, H: 120, HR: 5, AVG: 0.214")
        self.assertEqual(actual, expected)

  def test_delete_player_sucess(self):
    test_dict = {"Austin Riley": "AB: 615, R: 90, H: 168, HR: 38, AVG: 0.273"}
    expected = {}
    actual = delete_in_dict(test_dict, "Austin Riley")
    self.assertEqual(actual, expected)

  def test_delete_word_no_result(self):
    test_dict = {"Austin Riley": "AB: 615, R: 90, H: 168, HR: 38, AVG: 0.273"}
    expected = test_dict
    actual = delete_in_dict(test_dict, "Shohei Ohtani")
    self.assertEqual(actual, expected)


#uncomment to run tests
unittest.main()
```

The error message:

self.assertEqual(actual, expected)
AssertionError: {'Austin Riley': 'AB: 615, R: 90, H: 168, HR: 38, AVG: 0.2[63 chars]214'} != {'Austin Riley': ['AB: 615, R: 90, H: 168, HR: 38, AVG: 0.[46 chars]14']}

- {'Austin Riley': 'AB: 615, R: 90, H: 168, HR: 38, AVG: 0.273',

- {'Austin Riley': ['AB: 615, R: 90, H: 168, HR: 38, AVG: 0.273',
  ?                  +

- 'Austin Riley(2)': 'AB: 350, R: 20, H: 120, HR: 5, AVG: 0.214'}

- ```
                'AB: 350, R: 20, H: 120, HR: 5, AVG: 0.214']}
  ```

Comment: Your assertion works fine there. The problem in your `add_player_to_dict`. It's does not work as your test suggests, so you need to fix it.